# C++ Builder bizarre issue (taskbar icon not appearing)?

Tags: forms, icons, c++builder, taskbar

I have an application with a login form (which is the main form) and a main form, which is opened after the log-in one is filled in with the correct info.

However, the program icon does not appear on the taskbar. I would like to ask, why does this happen?

[image: screenshot-1]

[image: screenshot-2]

Comment: We would also like to know. What is your code?

Comment: Your Login Form should not be your actual MainForm. Create the Login Form dynamically and show it, then show the actual MainForm if the Login is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything bizarre in this behaviour.
I assume You hide login form after user provides login information?

By default Main form owns taskbar:

```
Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
```

So either make frmMain "main" instead of LoginForm and create login form dynamically before main Form (this will make login form invisible on taskbar) or add following code to frmMain - 
in header:

```
void __fastcall CreateParams(Controls::TCreateParams &Params);
```

and in the .cpp file:

```
void __fastcall frmMain::CreateParams(Controls::TCreateParams &Params)
{
  TForm::CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle   = Params.ExStyle | WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  Params.WndParent = ParentWindow;
}
```

WS_EX_APPWINDOW "Forces a top-level window onto the taskbar when the window is visible."

As described in this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969325.aspx) article

and [Embarcadero DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Controls.TCreateParams).